# Shortening substitutes for pan greasing

Tags: substitutions, shortening

[An answer to a question of mine](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/44681/how-to-line-this-cake-pan-with-parchment-paper/44692#44692) suggests that a  non-stick (bundt) pan plus the cake release will be enough. The suggested formula is

> 1 part vegetable oil, 1 part shortening and 1 part flour

I want a substitution for shortening for this application. I also read in [another answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/are-there-any-substitutes-for-shortening/7178#7178) that canned cooking sprays could be used as well, but I couldn't get it as well.

Comment: see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18249/greasing-a-pan-with-butter-vs-with-shortening

Answer (score 2):

Shortening is used here because it is solid at room temperature so it adheres to the sides of the pan and provides a better barrier. Spray oil can do ok and has emulsifiers in it to help it along but solid fat works better.

An obvious substitute is butter. Actually butter can be substituted for shortening in a lot of applications (with the exception of when the shortening is being used for its high smoke point.) Some saturated fats, like coconut oil, might have more flavor than you want.

If you are looking for more convenience- they make non-stick spray that has flour in it as well exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Softened butter should do a good enough job in this situation. You could conceivably use ghee but that might flavour the cake.